# Organizing data to run regression

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

I have experience with both regression and R but am a bit puzzled with how exactly to set up this regression. I am looking at sporting events where two teams play head to head. From each of these games I have the statistics for those games for the winning team and the losing team. I want to predict the MOV based on a number of those statistics. Here is how I currently have the data set up:

```
Year    Winning_TM     Winning_TM_Pts    Losing_TM    Losing_TM_Pts  MOV ...  
2011    A              45                B            32             13
2012    C              27                D            25             2
...
```

There is much more data but I think you can see how the data is arranged currently. **My concern is what effects this will have on the model when in the future I want to predict the margin of victory for a given team?** Is there a better way to organize this data so that the model meets its purpose and doesn't?

Note: The model set up, in my mind, would look something like this (possibly with other statistics depending on their utility):

```
MOV ~ Yds_Rush + Yds_Pass + SOS
```

Comment: Wouldn't the prediction MOV = Winning_TM_Pts - Losing_TM_Pts work perfectly, without any need for statistical analysis?  I think it would continue to be highly accurate in the future, too.  Clearly I am being facetious, but there's a point to it: exactly what kind of "model" do you have in mind?  If it's not one that predicts the points for each team, then what is it exactly?

Comment: That is what I am asking. I am just wondering if there will be any influence by having the data sorted by winning team and not randomly between winning or losing team. Maybe I am overthinking the set up